# Binding a property value to comparation of two variable values

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, controls

In my WPF application i'm trying to bind my IsEnabled value of a control to the result of a comparation of two values.

Take val1 and val2
if val1 == val2 then IsEnabled should be true, otherwise it should be false

val1 and val2 can both change during the application

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: so what's the prob if both the changed you have to enable only when both are equal

Comment: @RazorEater is `val1` and `val2` part of the same view model?

Comment: @dkozl they are not, would it help me if they were?

Comment: then it looks like you need converter

Comment: @DhavalPatel i am missing what you are trying to say.. the problem is that IsEnabled should be true if val1 == val2 == 2 or val1 == val2 == 3, ... but it doesn't seem to do that

Comment: @dkozl yes, i am using a converter right now. But the Convert method isn't called after changing a value, so the isEnabled property does not change

Comment: @RazorEater `val1` and `val2` need to raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event and you need to bind both properties with `MultiBinding` and your converter. If they were part of one view model you could create another property `valCondition` and raise `PropertyChanged` event for `valCondition` whenever `val1` or `val2` changed value

Comment: Can you create it as observable property as "IsEnabled"  and assign to the control which needs to be enabled or disabled ? and also keep Val1 and Val2 as observable. So a soon as value of Val1 or Val2 will be changed, it will raise change for "isEnabled" and so on.

Comment: @dkozl could you explain "you need to bind both properties with MultiBinding and your converter" or give a code example?

Comment: @Bhaarat Observable seems pretty usefull, but your solution is the same as dkozl's but with a wrapper

Comment: I don't know how you use converter at the moment you need to create `MultiBinding` for `IsEnabled` with 2 `Bindings` for `val1` and `val2` and converter that would compare is `values` passed to `IMultiValueConverter` are equal. Maybe post your use of converter and relevant parts of view models otherwise it may be difficult to write good answer

Comment: [CodeProject article on IMultiValueConverter and MultiBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328978/Introduction-to-multi-binding-and-multi-value-conv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely use a converter. To do this you need to implement the IMultiValueConverter. Here is an example.

Converter:

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert( object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return ( (int)values[ 0 ] == (int)values[ 1 ] );
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack( object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And create the IsEnabled-multibinding using the converter.
Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication61.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication61">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.IsEnabled>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Value1" />
                <Binding Path="Value2" />                                  
            </MultiBinding>
        </Grid.IsEnabled>

        <Button Content="Just a button" Width="75" Height="30" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Random random;

    private int m_Value1;
    public int Value1
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Value1;
        }
        set
        {
            if ( m_Value1 == value )
            {
               return;
            }

            m_Value1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int m_Value2;
    public int Value2
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Value2;
        }
        set
        {
            if ( m_Value2 == value )
            {
                return;
            }

            m_Value2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        random = new Random();

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Elapsed( object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e )
    {
        Value1 = random.Next( 0, 2 );
        Value2 = random.Next( 0, 2 );
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "" )
    {
        if ( PropertyChanged != null )
        {
            PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Notice that the button is just to illustrate that the IsEnabled is toggled.

Happy coding :-)